# Has complete Moravia's "Racconti romani" been translated to English?

Tags: short-stories, translation, italian-language, alberto-moravia

At Internet Archive one can find a book with the title [*Roman tales*](https://archive.org/details/romantales00mora/mode/1up), which is in fact a selection of Moravia's *Racconti romani* translated to English by Angus Davidson and published in 1959. In words of the translator,

> I have been guided in my selection not only by personal preference, but also by the question of suitability for the English reader. Some of the stories in the Italian collection are so very Roman in character  –so dependent on allusions to places or events of local interest– that it would be impossible to retain their full flavour in translation, or to make them easily intelligible to the majority of English readers.

That maybe was an usual approach to translation in 1950s (I really don't know), but lots of things may have happened since then. The fact is that these "so very Roman in character" stories are very interesting, so I wonder if a translation to English of the whole *Racconti romani* book or, at least, something more complete than that by Angus Davidson exists.

I haven't seen it at page 135 of this [*Italian Literature since 1900 in English Translation 1929-2016*](https://books.google.it/books?id=CZiRDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA315), but I don't have access to other pages of this book, so perhaps I'm missing some relevant piece of information.

So, my question would be: is there a more complete translation of Moravia's *Racconti romani*?

Comment: Congrats on 2k reputation, enjoy the new [tools](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tools) :-)

Comment: Healey's bibliography only lists Davidson's selected translation (in various imprints between 1956 and 1988).